# Typescript: Excluding all required properties from a type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-types

How do I have to define in the following code type `ExcludeAllRequiredProps<T>` to exclude (like the name says) all required properties? Thanks in advance.

```
type A = {
  a: number,
  b: number,
  c?: number,
  d?: number
}

type B = ExcludeAllRequiredProps<A>


// B shall be { c?: number, d?: number }
```

---

[Edit - a while later]

Do you consider this a proper solution?

```
type ExcludeAllRequiredProps<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: T extends Record<K, T[K]> ? never : T[K]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is close, but it keeps those extra keys along, which might cause confusion even if they are of type `never`. This solution will remove the unwanted keys from the result:

```
type ExcludeAllRequiredProps<T> = Pick<T, {
    [K in keyof T]-?: T extends Record<K, T[K]> ? never : K
}[keyof T]>

type A = {
    a: number,
    b: number,
    c?: number,
    d?: number
}

type B = ExcludeAllRequiredProps<A> // { c?: number, d?: number }
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks. One question: Is this "-?" really necessary? I do not see a difference without it...

Comment: @Natasha I added it out of habit, sometimes under strict null checks and extra `undefined` creeps into the keys if we don't use `-?` and coses problems in other places. Probably here it makes no difference.